# How to create a relative symlink in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

In my playbook, I need to create a symbolic link for a repo.

With command (shell) it may work like this:

```yaml
########## Create symbolic link 
- name: Create symbolic link 
  shell : ln   -s  "{{SOURCE_FOLDER}}"  SYMLINK
  args :
    chdir : "/opt/application/i99/"
  when:
    - ansible_host in groups['ihm']
```

**->**  like this my symbolic link is created directly inside **i99** repo /

`SYMLINK` **->** `SOURCE_FOLDER`

But while doing it with the Ansible file module, like this:

```yaml
########## Create symbolic link 
- name: Create symbolic link 
  file:
   src: "/opt/application/i99/{{SOURCE_FOLDER}}/"
   dest: "/opt/application/i99/SYMLINK"
   state: link
  when:
    - ansible_host in groups['ihm']
```

My output is this :

`SYMLINK` **->** `/opt/application/i99/SOURCE_FOLDER`

As I don't want that it points to the whole path, and I need to obtain the first format:

**SYMLINK -> SOURCE_FOLDER**

How can I do it?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Simply:

```
- name: Create symbolic link 
  file:
    src: "{{SOURCE_FOLDER}}"
    dest: "/opt/application/i99/SYMLINK"
    state: link
```

As you can see in [the manual for the `file` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html):

> `src` 　Will accept absolute, relative and nonexisting paths. Relative paths are not expanded.

Comment: `dest:` is now being called `path:` in the documentation, but is still valid as an alias.

Comment: `dest` and `name` are valid aliases for `path` according to the latest documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html