# Ansible playbook create relative link

Tags: ansible

Could someone let me know how to create a relative symlink.

I have files under following folder.

```
/usr/share/aws/hive/encryption/test-1.2.3.jar
```

And I was to create link in this folder which points to this jar. something like

```
test.jar -> test-1.2.3.jar
```

However with following ansible code, it takes absolute path.

```
  - name: create soft link
    file:
        src: "/usr/share/aws/hive/encryption/test-1.2.3.jar"
        dest: "/usr/share/aws/hive/encryption/test.jar"
        state: link
        force: yes
```

**outout**

```
test.jar -> /usr/share/aws/hive/encryption/test-1.2.3.jar
```

Comment: check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560311/ansible-create-a-relative-symlink

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```yaml
  - name: create soft link
    file:
        src: "test-1.2.3.jar"
        path: "/usr/share/aws/hive/encryption/test.jar"
        state: link
        force: yes
```

Quoting from [parameter src](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html#parameter-src):

> Relative paths are relative to the file being created (path) which is how the Unix command ln -s SRC DEST treats relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the shell module instead. In your case, if is taking the absolute path, because thats how source and destination are given.

```
- name: Create a Symlink
  shell:
    cmd: ln -s test-1.2.3.jar test.jar
    chdir: /usr/share/aws/hive/encryption/
```

Comment: is there a way I can give source and destination in different way?

Comment: I believe vladimir answer should work for you.
what do you mean different way? do you want use variables ?